# Why is this false? $\int \frac{dx}{(e^{x}+e^{-x})^{2}} = \frac{1}{4}\tanh x+c$ [turns out it isn't false]

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Can some explain to me why this is not true?
$$\int \frac{dx}{(e^{x}+e^{-x})^{2}} = \frac{1}{4}\tanh x+c$$

$$\int \frac{dx}{(e^{x}+e^{-x})^{2}} = \frac{1}{4}\int \frac{dx}{(\frac{e^{x}+e^{-x}}{2})^{2}} = \frac{1}{4} \int \frac{1}{(\cosh x)^{2}} = \frac{1}{4} \tanh + C$$

My equation.
[image: my equation]

Comment: It will be appreciated if you type up your work. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: What makes you think it is false?

Comment: thanks, I added it. I thought it was false since Wolfram Apha said so

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact what you wrote is right.

On the one hand,
$$
\int\frac1{(e^x+e^{-x})^2}dx=\frac14\int\frac1{\cosh^2 x}dx=\frac14 \tanh x+C_1=\frac14 \frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}+C_1, \tag1
$$ on the other hand
$$
\int\frac1{(e^x+e^{-x})^2}dx=-\frac1{2(1+e^{2x})}+C_2 \tag2
$$ We have that $(1)$ and $(2)$ agree with appropriate constants $C_1,C_2$.

Comment: @Tim You are welcome.